# How to enable Num Lock after login in 12.10?

Tags: keyboard-layout, numlock

I tried to set options in keyboard layout. I enabled "default numeric keys" but no success. I want it to be enabled only after login. I see the options in keyboard layout are slightly altered in 12.10.

How do I do it in 12.10?

Comment: Have you tried logging out then logging back in?

Answer (score 2):

**To enable Numlock on Login**

> Go to **System Settings → Keyboard Layout → Options → Miscellaneous compatibility** options and check "**Default numeric keypad keys**"

1. Go to **System Settings...**

   [image]
2. Select **Keyboard Layout**

   [image]
3. Select keyboard layout on the left pane and click on **Options** on the lower right corner.

   [image]
4. Under **Keyboard Layout Options** window, click on **Miscellaneous Compatibility options** and tick **Default numeric keypad keys**.

   [image]
5. Click on **Close**.

Setting takes effect after Login.

Comment: I had done the same and restarted the pc.I guess I had selected some other option too,which may have disabled auto num lock.I have a usb wireless keyboard.Perhaps this is the reason sometimes things do not work at first attempt.This time it worked,thank you.

Comment: FYI: This answer no longer works, and is not correct as of 14.01